# List sorting algorithm for comparisons done by humans

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This question was asked once before but not answered so I thought I would ask again with some specifics to my situation.

I am trying to develop an app that lets you put in a list of discrete items (for this example, fruit) and it offers you comparisons between two. You choose your favourite of the two and then this process repeats until eventually you have a list ordered by preference of these objects (in this example, a list of your favourite fruit, in order).

The issue is that traditional sorting strategies, no matter how fast, are going to necessarily involve more operations than is feasible for a human to do in any sensible amount of time (even with a list as short as 50, as my current test list is).

Since obviously there isn't a guaranteed sorting algorithm with low enough complexity, I guess some allowances have to made. Is there a way to skip out large chunks of sorting? I considered some way of assigning values to items based on the number of comparisons they've 'won' and then stopping the sort after a while and assuming that those values give the correct order, similar to the style that you might resolve a swiss chess tournament if you cant complete enough rounds to determine a winner normally. I dont know if that is plausible.

An example to clarify what I mean:
say you had a list of

```
Apple
Orange
Kiwi
Banana
Melon
```

It would offer you comparisons like

```
Do you prefer:
A Apple
B Kiwi
```

and so on until you have a list that looks like

```
Kiwi
Apple
Orange
Melon
Banana
```

which is your order of preference of those fruit.

Comment: What exactly are the comparisons being offered? Could you clarify what you mean by showing the steps you would take with a 5-element array?

Comment: @jperezov added an example to my original post

Comment: This can be solved with a completely different approach. Rather than asking the user to rank each individual item, give them a list and an easy way of moving things up and down in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are your fruit preferences? Do you have a full ordered list of preferences in your mind, or do you have fruits you "like more than most," fruits you "like less than most," and the rest which you don't have any strong feelings about - or you haven't even tried.

The problem with how you have formulated your problem is that you have assumed that a person's preferences are a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), which is naturally encoded as a list. Really, a person's preferences are often a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), which is naturally encoded as a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

For example, for the set of fruits `{Apple, Orange, Kiwi, Banana, Melon, Starfruit}`, I might have fruit preferences as follows:

```
Melon < Apple
Apple < Banana
Banana < Kiwi
Banana < Orange
```

A good way to arrive at a partial order based on user input is to mimic [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). To start, ask the user to select, for each fruit, whether they like it, dislike it, feel neutral about it, or don't know. I would answer that as follows:

```
            Like Dislike Neutral Unknown
Apple                    x
Orange      x
Kiwi        x
Banana      x
Melon            x
Starfruit                        x
```

Assuming `Dislike < Neutral < Like`, these answers encode the following information, even though I've only answered as many questions as there are fruits:

```
Melon < Apple
Apple < Orange
Apple < Kiwi
Apple < Banana
```

Next, identify which answer(s) received the most check marks. In this case, I seem to have 3 fruits I like, 1 I dislike, and 1 I feel neutral about (unless peanut butter is involved), and 1 I've never tried (so I don't have any preference with respect to the other fruits).

So the natural place to further investigate my preferences would be within the fruits I like. The problem is recursive: now you want to determine my preferences in the set of fruits `{Orange, Kiwi, Banana}`. You could ask me which of those fruits are my favorite, and I'd click `Orange` and `Kiwi`. That tells you the following:

```
Banana < Orange
Banana < Kiwi
```

Combined with the first round of information, you now have:

```
Melon < Apple
Apple < Orange
Apple < Kiwi
Apple < Banana
Banana < Kiwi
Banana < Orange
```

`Apple < Banana` and `Banana < Kiwi` imply `Apple < Kiwi`; `Apple < Banana` and `Banana < Orange` imply `Apple < Orange`. So we can eliminate the redundant information to arrive at the following:

```
Melon < Apple
Apple < Banana
Banana < Kiwi
Banana < Orange
```

Comment: This an interesting idea, how do you think that data could be displayed in a more easily readable manner?

Comment: @CountBale If you restrict the user preferences to look like `{A, B, C} < {D, E} < {F, G, H} < {I} < {J, K, L, M}` plus some unranked `{X, Y, Z}` (like `Starfruit` in my example), then you can display the user preferences as a list of groups, where every item in a group is preferable to every item in every lower group.  My fruit preferences would look like this: `{Melon} < {Apple} < {Banana} < {Kiwi, Orange}` + unranked `{Starfruit}`.

Answer (score 3):

You could let the user not only give whether an item is more preferable than another, but also a rating from 1 to 10 for example how much more he prefers the one from the other. That way you have more information and can easily create a ranking.

In the optimal approach where a user can only say smaller or bigger you need to perform binary search for each item in the list. Binary search has complexity `O(log n)`. Doing this `n` times with `n` going from 1 to `n` makes a total of 
`O(n * log (n/2))`. In case of 50 items that would require a bit more than 200 steps.

Comment: I like the first idea, although rather than an explicit 1 to 10 rating I'd probably implement it as something like:
Very A > A > Slightly A > No Preference > Slightly B > B > Very B or something along those lines. I'll need to figure out how exactly to use those values in the algorithm though

Comment: +1 for the rating. Rating 50 items and sorting based on the rating would be much faster than doing any number of comparisons.

Comment: But the issue with just giving everything a rating is that it forces you to consider all of the data at once to really rate anything. Giving something 89 is meaningless without the context of the entire set of data. I wanted to make an app that simplified the process of ordering the list so that you only have to consider two items at once.

Comment: @CountBale if you're going to compare two items at a time you *can't* do better than n*log(n) for a full sort, that's been proven. You need to choose a different approach or simplify the problem in some way if you want a practical solution.

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah, currently I'm trying to work out how high I can make the number of items per comparison without making it too many to keep in headspace at once

Answer (score 2):

Use an [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). Instead of asking the user to compare two items at a time, ask them to select their favorite from the entire remaining list. Put that item at the end of the sorted list, remove it from the remaining items, and repeat until the remaining items are exhausted.

Comment: I'm considering a middle ground between this and my initial idea. Perhaps offering the user a choice of 10 items and asking them to pick their favourite from those, then iterating that until the data set is sorted. It would be higher than N complexity but it would also allow the user to consider less data at any given time.